# Access token appears to be incorrect format using auth0-react library

Tags: reactjs, jwt, auth0

I am following [this blog post](https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication/) on how to use the [auth0-react library](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react).

The post describes using the `getAccessTokenSilently` from the `useAuth0` hook to get the access token which is used as the bearer token

```
  const callSecureApi = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();

      const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/private-message`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });

      const responseData = await response.json();

      setMessage(responseData);
    } catch (error) {
      setMessage(error.message);
    }
  };
```

The issue I'm having is the token doesn't appear to be a JWT token - it looks like:

```
RJq7USOcszn7rpyI5iDjbYAKp9pK60Ap
```

Does anyone know why `getAccessTokenSilently` isn't returning a JWT token?

Comment: Are you sure the accesstoken should be a JWT? There is a difference between ID tokens (always jwt) and access tokens:  https://auth0.com/docs/tokens

Comment: Hi, I expect a bearer token to be a JWT token. You can see in the code in my original post is being used as the bearer token which I got from their blog post: https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication/.

The token that's being returned (`RJq7USOcszn7rpyI5iDjbYAKp9pK60Ap` or similar) is not a bearer token.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The same task took me a while as well, the docs are neither very clear nor up-to-date there I feel. Here is what you need to do:

1. For Auth0, you need both a Single Page Application under "Applications", **and** an API under "APIs"
2. Your React App gets wrapped with something like the below. Note the audience parameter from your API, this is the crucial part, without it, I also got the same small and useless access token you got!

```
<Auth0Provider
    domain={AUTH0_DOMAIN} // taken from the SPA application in Auth0
    clientId={AUTH0_CLIENT_ID} // taken from the SPA application in Auth0
    authorizationParams={{
        audience={AUTH0_AUDIENCE} // taken from your API in Auth0
        redirectUri={window.location.origin}
    }}
    useRefreshTokens={true}
    cacheLocation={"localstorage"}
>
```

3. Wherever you want to call your Backend (e.g. Spring Boot), you add the following to the component:

```
const {user, getAccessTokenSilently} = useAuth0();
...
// this will now be a JWT token, BUT ONLY if you specified the API audience in the Auth0Provider
// looks something like this:
/* eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IlFqZEVNMEU1TnpWRE0wTkRSRVEzUkVFMFFVSkJOamMwUmtGRE1qZzNPVGxCTURNMk56UTJSZyJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3JhcGlkbWluZXIuYXV0aDAuY29tLyIsGnN1YiI6ImF1dGgwfDUzNDc5YzMwNmU5Yjc4YTU3MzAwMDVjNSIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwczovL2VuZ2luZWVyaW5nLXRvb2xzLnJhcGlkbWluZXIuY29tL2FwaSIsImh0dHBzOi8vcmFwaWRtaW5lci5hdXRoMC5jb20vdXNlcmluZm8iXSwiaWF0IjoxNTk2ODM2MDMyLCJleHAiOjE1OTY5MjI0MzIsImF6cCI6IllldWhoS29JV1lTV2FYUmExNU1sNTFMZUExYkp4bjVlIiwic2NvcGUiOiJvcGVuaWQgcHJvZmlsZSBlbWFpbCJ9.zI74HHd1pCzz-xBQEDDKby9z_Ue9_AIz-r05_my1wvLQ0U94u9WrwWmSxd9BQ-2XOHKa1KgnaaxsX2aiSHil7a4YjMnrYo9f0jgMmlxcllqZJgeb0AhLQNfYQEr6nAKP_8PgN0D7QFjIxiFTpDndTcD_2nG9DEsxbraT7dDy0pf1KTGmhQnNyBuyReAEUFhlxd1LAd63ED14nCPmEehl5rLNUwClTRFQ5q4ERLjM8cX0GLLy5F-I7UjpDOBnrL_qMqfuHyuChxs-k0fHhhEfV8xE2nEV00cXcAp3zvpJ_Ox9U0OBaVUbf1vi9v1Wl6jaMZpgqRZ1bZcfDXWjoEBVlQ */
const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();
```

4. Now you can pass the accessToken along via `Authorization` header:

```
headers: {
    "Authorization": `bearer ${accessToken}`
}
```

5. Your BE can now validate the regular JWT token.

Comment: Thanks for this!!  I noticed you've not included `onRedirectCallback` in your Auth0Provider like in the docs. Do you not need to use it? The reason I ask is that following the docs means I need to use `react-router-dom`, which isn't the router I actually want to use.

Comment: I followed https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login, which does not mention the `onRedirectCallback`, so I'm afraid I don't know. It works fine for me, but I indeed use `react-router-dom`.

Comment: Im working on Angular, but your answer definitely have the solution! the problem was the authorizationParams (on my app.module.ts, imports) , it was missing the audience property and value, but the auth0 docs doesnt mention that anywhere. lifesaving!

Comment: I'm using Vue 3 with Nuxt and can confirm that this works for me too. This is a well explained answer. I was able to fix my issue with the information within minutes. FYI: the audience value can be found on the same page where the API application is set up

Comment: Wow, this is enraging.  The single most common use case, and the vital piece of information is not on their website.

Answer (score 2):

From [Auth0 docs](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/implicit-grant#2-extract-the-access-token):

> `id_token`: contains an ID Token and is present if the request parameter response_type included the value `id_token`, or the scope request parameter the value `openid`

From various Auth0 employees in the Auth0 forums:

- [How to get an access token in JWT format?](https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-get-an-access-token-in-jwt-format/6185/2#post_2)

  > if you update the scope parameter to specify `openid` ... then you should receive a response containing an `id_token` parameter that would indeed be a signed JWT
- [OIDC Access Token (mine is opaque, but docs say it should be JWT)](https://community.auth0.com/t/oidc-access-token-mine-is-opaque-but-docs-say-it-should-be-jwt/18601/2)

  In addition to specifying `openid`:

  > If you specify an audience, and the audience is a custom API you built, then you’ll get a JWT token

So, in the [options](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/blob/82807e383030d798962cf9eb89fd1354c3f2e174/src/global.ts#L227) object of `getAccessTokenSilently`, make sure:

- the `scope` parameter includes `openid`
- the `audience` parameter refers to your API